# Ignore condition in WHERE clause when column is NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I do have table were one row (with Type =E) is related to another row. 
I have written query to return COUNT of those related rows. The problem is that there is no explicit relationship (like ID column that would clearly say which row is related to other row). Therefore I am trying to find relationship based on multiple conditions in WHERE clause.

The problem is that in few cases, the columns A and B could be NULL (for records where TYPE = 'M'). In such a cases I would like to ignore that condition, so It would use only first 3 conditions to determine relationship.

I have tried CASE Statement but is not working as expected:

```
SELECT  [T1].[ID],[T1].[AlphaId],[T1].[Type],[T1].[A],[T1].[B],[T1].[Date],[T1].[ServiceID]
        ,(  SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM MyTable T2
            WHERE   [T1].[AlphaId]=[T2].[AlphaId] AND
                    [T1].[Date]=[T2].[Date] AND
                    [T1].[ServiceID]=[T2].[ServiceID] AND
                    [T2].[A]=CASE WHEN [T2].[A] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [T1].[A] END AND
                    [T2].[B]=CASE WHEN [T2].[B] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [T1].[B] END AND
                    [T2].[Type]='M'
        ) as TotalCount

FROM MyTable T1
WHERE [T1].[Type] = 'E'
```

I can't ignore that condition, as for some cases the Date, ServiceID could be same, however it's the A, B which differs them. Luckily where A, B IS NULL, it is the Date, ServiceID which differs those two records.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c98db/1

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, this is the same as my query just with added brackets

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56438/4

Answer (score 0):

You could join the tables and use COUNT and GROUP BY to get the counts. Then you can JOIN [A] and [B] if they are equal or NULL.

```
SELECT [T1].[ID],[T1].[AlphaId],[T1].[Type],[T1].[A],[T1].[B],[T1].[Date],[T1].[ServiceID], count([T2].[ID])
FROM MyTable T1
INNER JOIN MyTable T2 ON [T1].[AlphaId]=[T2].[AlphaId] AND
                    [T1].[Date]=[T2].[Date] AND
                    [T1].[ServiceID]=[T2].[ServiceID] AND
                    ([T2].[A]= [T1].[A] OR [T2].[A] IS NULL )AND
                    ([T2].[B]= [T1].[B] OR [T2].[B] IS NULL )AND
                    [T2].[Type] <> [T1].[Type]
WHERE [T1].[Type] = 'E'

GROUP BY [T1].[ID],[T1].[AlphaId],[T1].[Type],[T1].[A],[T1].[B],[T1].[Date],[T1].[ServiceID]
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry I should have mentioned this in my question. Unfortunately I can't do this as reality you can have multiple records where ServiceID = BB01 and I also need to get Count of cases where LEFT(ServiceID,2) = 'CC'. When you join those two tables, number of rows get multiplied, so the third column is counted twice. Here is new sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/875e9/1

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you're expecting as a result?

Comment: @Petrik Please update your question with your requirements rather than add requirements as comments. Please can you also use the SQLFiddle Markdown feature to put code and results in your question, it makes it much easier for us to help you.